# Visualize a mesh from list of 3D point and faces

Tags: matlab, mesh-generation, mesh

I have a list of vertices and faces. Now, I want to create a mesh using the given points and faces list and visualize it. Also, I want to play with the mesh by adding an extra point on the faces. Can anybody guide me on how to do this using matlab? Any function name or guide would be helpful. I found a way to create a mesh using the range of the `x` and `y` but not using the given point so any direction would be helpful.

| Vertex | Position |
| --- | --- |
| P0 | 31.1041, 28.3457, 29.165 |
| P1 | 40.6266, 28.3457, -1.10804 |
| P2 | 40.0714, 30.4443, -1.10804 |
| P3 | 40.7155, 31.1438, -1.10804 |
| P4 | 42.0257, 30.4443, -1.10804 |
| P5 | 43.4692, 28.3457, -1.10804 |
| P6 | 37.5425, 28.3457, 14.5117 |
| P7 | 37.0303, 30.4443, 14.2938 |
| P8 | 37.6244, 31.1438, 14.5466 |
| P9 | 38.8331, 30.4443, 15.0609 |
| P10 | 40.1647, 28.3457, 15.6274 |
| P11 | 29.0859, 28.3457, 27.1468 |
| P12 | 28.6917, 30.4443, 26.7527 |
| P13 | 29.149, 31.1438, 27.2099 |
| P14 | 30.0792, 30.4443, 28.1402 |

| face id | vertices id |
| --- | --- |
| face 0 | 7,6,1 |
| face 1 | 1,2,7 |
| face 2 | 8,7,2 |
| face 3 | 2,3,8 |
| face 4 | 9,8,3 |
| face 5 | 3,4,9 |
| face 6 | 10,9,4 |
| face 7 | 13,12,7 |

Comment: It is related to CompScie.SE very tangentially, but if you are OK to use Python, look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58617015/10382271

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36275/vtk-python-visualizing-scalar-data-on-quad-mesh/36287#3628  might be useful as well.

Comment: @Nachiket thanks. I will check it out. seems similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the [`trimesh` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trimesh.html).

In your case, you would have something like

```matlab
pts = [31.1041, 28.3457, 29.165;
    40.6266, 28.3457, -1.10804;
    40.0714, 30.4443, -1.10804;
    40.7155, 31.1438, -1.10804;
    42.0257, 30.4443, -1.10804;
    43.4692, 28.3457, -1.10804;
    37.5425, 28.3457, 14.5117;
    37.0303, 30.4443, 14.2938;
    37.6244, 31.1438, 14.5466;
    38.8331, 30.4443, 15.0609;
    40.1647, 28.3457, 15.6274;
    29.0859, 28.3457, 27.1468;
    28.6917, 30.4443, 26.7527;
    29.149, 31.1438, 27.2099;
    30.0792, 30.4443, 28.1402];

T = [7, 6, 1;
    1, 2, 7;
    8, 7, 2;
    2, 3, 8;
    9, 8, 3;
    3, 4, 9;
    10, 9, 4;
    13, 12, 7];

trimesh(T, pts(:, 1), pts(:, 2), pts(:, 3))
```

But it seems to have some overlapping triangles.

Comment: thanks. it is something similar. but rather than fixing the face for the 3 points, I would like to make faces of variable points (3,4, or 6 points). Do you know whether that is possible or not?

Comment: @nKandel, I think that in that case you would need to create your own function. Or find a better visualization library or an external software.